# training and testing in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow

How to have the accuracy of training data - it should always be 100% if it is their.
I can understand  how we are getting the validation accuracy that we are just checking with the result but how can we get the testing accuracy?

Answer (score 0):

In supervised learning, the input data along with the target labels can be divided into training, validation and testing data. Just like training accuracy and validation accuracy, testing accuracy is the accuracy on the training data. Following steps are usually involved in evaluating the model:

- The model predicts the result for each input in the testing data
- The results are compared with the target labels
- Accuracy percentage is calculated